# angular-typescript dynamic object creation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi i am trying to get ID card details in a component and form an object "idCardDetails".
In JS i was able to dynamicaly add key and values :
`let myObj = {}; myObj.name = "sid"; myObj.num= 4444;`

I cant create such a dynamic obj in Type script.

I tried this in TS angular
`IdCardDetails: {name: string, empcode: number, bloodgroup: string}; IdCardDetails.name = this.idName; // error cannot set property for undefined` 
Is this a error occurring with rules of Typescript or Angular?
what will be solution to dynamicaly create an object?
Is it necessary always go with class based object creation in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of options for the task you want.

first if you know the fields create an `interface`

```js
export interface ITest {
name:string,  // this will make sure ITest must have name in string type.
age?:number, // this will allow you not to enter age (can be undefined)
[key:string]: any, // will allow you to put what ever key you would like (is more powerful but typescript will not always complete example below,
}
```

```js
// notice I can avoid using age.
const test:ITest = {
name:'test' // I must provide some initial string 
}

test.value = true; // will be accepted because of [key:string]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know all keys in advance then you can use TypeScript's `Record` utility in the following fashion where `Keys` are the object types and `Type` is the type you want the object should have

```
Record<Keys, Type>
```

So, you'd write your code as below,

```
const idCardDetails: Record<string, number | string> = {};

idCardDetails.name = 'John';
idCardDetails.id = 10;
```

You can read more about [Record utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

Comment: Thankyou, I should be learning the concept of interface I think :)  . But what if we don't know the keys to be present in the object initially. Like in the js example in my question , is it not possible to create a empty object and later add key and corresponding values?

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer. Let me know